# JSON to textView?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have my app get JSON data from a link, but I need to get status from the JSON.

- Status > Code and Msg.

Here is what I have working:

Screenshot:

[image]

I need to have it output >

1. Code : success (or fail, whatever the json says)
2. Msg : Licence updated.. (Or whatever the JSON spits out)

Any help would be nice or pointing me in the direction, thanks.

Some of my code:

```
public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
String words;

        public doit() throws JSONException {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                EditText messages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.deepbot.tv/web/apply/namerefresh.php?s=" + messages.getText().toString()).get();

                words=doc.text();

            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            texx.setText(words);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First create a `JSONObject` with response string `words`.

```
    JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(words);
```

**2.** Get the JSONObject `status` from your response JSONObject `words`:

```
    JSONObject  jsonObjectStatus = jsonObject.getJSONObject("status");
```

**3.** Finally, parse `code` and `msg` string from `status` JSONObject as below:

```
    String code = jsonObjectStatus.getString("code");
    String msg = jsonObjectStatus.getString("msg");
```

**Update `onPostExecute()` as below:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {
            JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(words);
            JSONObject  jsonObjectStatus = jsonObject.getJSONObject("status");

            String code = jsonObjectStatus.getString("code");
            String msg = jsonObjectStatus.getString("msg");

            texx.setText("Code: " + code + "\nMessage: " + msg);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, just replace your return:

```
   public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
   String words;

    public doit() throws JSONException {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            EditText messages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messages);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.deepbot.tv/web/apply/namerefresh.php?s=" + messages.getText().toString()).get();

            words=doc.text();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        return words;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    try {
        JSONObject  jObj = new JSONObject(words);
        String code = jObj.getString("code");
        String name = jObj.getString("msg");
        texx.setText(code +"  "+name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146440/discussion-on-answer-by-nilesh-rathod-json-to-textview).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout awesome library [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)
You just need to create Object for response, And you will get it like

```
Response response = gson.fromJson("words", Response.class);
```

response contains all your needs.

**OR**

You can go with [json parser tutorials](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

```
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(words);
String date = jObj.getString("msg");
```

> Blockquote